# Error in creating a new component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components

I tried to create a new component called signup-form using the command:

```
ng generate component signup-form / ng g component signup-form
```

I am getting this error:

> Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1154

I am unable to know from which json file i am getting this error.

Below is the `angular-cli.json` contents.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ylet": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {

      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ylet",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "C:/ylet/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.css",
              "C:/ylet/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.components.css",
              "C:/ylet/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.min.css",
              "C:/ylet/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.components.min.css",
              "C:/ylet/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "C:/ylet/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/js/fabric.min.js",
              "C:/ylet/node_modules/ng-office-ui-fabric/ngOfficeUiFabric.js",

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ylet:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ylet:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ylet:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [

            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ylet-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ylet:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ylet:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ylet"
}
```

Comment: Are you issuing two commands simultaneously? `ng generate component signup-form / ng g component signup-form` ?

Comment: No i tried with both the commands separately

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `angular-cli.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You have a trailing comma, in your `scripts` block (2nd line), Please remove it and save the file then try your ng generate.

```
"scripts": [
   "C:/ylet/node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/js/fabric.min.js",
   "C:/ylet/node_modules/ng-office-ui-fabric/ngOfficeUiFabric.js",
]
```

Comment: I have removed the comments still getting the same error

Comment: @Shankarguru Can you please update your post with your `angular-cli.json` file content?

Comment: @Shankarguru Please check my updated answer (under **Edit** above)

Comment: Are you sure that, you removed the comma from this line => `"C:/ylet/node_modules/ng-office-ui-fabric/ngOfficeUiFabric.js",` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use only "`ng g component signup-form`"